# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-64219 after upgrading to Oracle 19c from Oracle 11g

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle19c

We have JAVA EE project developed using JRE 1.6, Tomcat 6, Apache struts and Oracle 11g.
Recently we upgraded to JRE 1.8, Tomcat 9 and Oracle 19c.

After upgrading the setup, we are getting "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-64219: invalid LOB locator encountered" while reading data from blob using java code.

Below are the error snippet, it will be great help if we get some help to troubleshoot the issue

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-64219: invalid LOB locator encountered
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:189)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:242)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:554)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1478)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteFetch(TTC7Protocol.java:888)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeNonQuery(OracleStatement.java:2076)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteOther(OracleStatement.java:1986)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:2697)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:457)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:531)
    at oracle.sql.LobPlsqlUtil.plsql_getChunkSize(LobPlsqlUtil.java:1282)
    at oracle.sql.LobPlsqlUtil.plsql_getChunkSize(LobPlsqlUtil.java:129)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBAccess.getLobChunkSize(DBAccess.java:959)
    at oracle.sql.LobDBAccessImpl.getChunkSize(LobDBAccessImpl.java:116)
    at oracle.sql.BLOB.getChunkSize(BLOB.java:266)
    at oracle.sql.BLOB.getBufferSize(BLOB.java:280)
    at oracle.sql.BLOB.getBinaryStream(BLOB.java:162)
    at com.csgs.allocationschedule.action.ExportAllocationScheduleAction.writeFileStandardExcel(ExportAllocationScheduleAction.java:718)
    at com.csgs.allocationschedule.action.ExportAllocationScheduleAction.executeAction(ExportAllocationScheduleAction.java:292)
    at com.csgs.common.action.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:94)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:874)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: We can't troubleshoot an issue in code we can't see. Please edit your question to include the relevant Java code, or a [mcve].

Comment: It is database error how it's related to struts?